# Smoke came out of my transistor, but it still works. Why?

Tags: transistors

So I was playing around with some transistors to make amplifiers of type C and D. I turned on the voltage and immediatly saw smoke coming out of my transistor. Turned off the voltage and that was that. But I checked the transistor with my voltage meter, and every value was still correct. I tried to use it again (with the mistake in my circuit fixed) and it worked flawlessly.

So, what burned? What could have made the smoke that would not break the transistor if it did?

Comment: What is the transistor case made of?

Comment: Maybe it was just on a smoke break...

Comment: The case is just some plastic you find on any old transistor.

Comment: Seriously though,, it likely burned off some material but not enough to kill it before you shut the power off. It will likely be significantly in pain though... At the very least you lost the hermetic seal so life expectancy will be short...

Comment: Yeah, the "magic smoke" doesn't come from the silicon itself anyway.  It comes from plastic, adhesive, insulation, greases, flux residue, etc. Releasing it is highly correlated with killing your device, but not the same thing.

Comment: "But I checked the transistor with my voltage meter" Please clarify. If you turn it off and measure the transistor with a volt meter, you will measure 0.00 V. If you mean multimeter, please clarify what and how you measured.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Temperature can destroy your transistors in several ways:

If the dissipation was too high, but not enormous (say, 20W in a TO220 not mounted on a heat sink) then it will slowly overheat and the plastic will  smoke, but it will still work for a few seconds before the die cracks, or the bondwires melt. MOSFETs still work at 300°C, although not for very long! Since you cut the power it didn't reach that stage. You should not use this transistor again, as its characteristics could have shifted, also it will have a much higher probability of failure than a brand new one which hasn't been overcooked.

I believe this is what happened.

Also, MOSFETs work perfectly fine at 200°C (although lifetime is reduced). There is a particular model of car which has a MOSFET on one of the boards inside the dashboard to control the lights. They screwed up the thermal design, so the thing actually melts its own solder and falls off the board on speed bumps. But if you solder it back and add a heat sink, it'll still work...

Another way to kill a transistor is localized failure modes like second breakdown, thermal runaway, or avalanche, etc. In this case the transistor is dead, a tiny portion of the die inside will have blown and melted, shorting things out, sometimes without any external sign of any problem.

However, if dissipation is more on the "explosive" side, like shorting a 4700µF capacitor charged to 30V with a MOSFET... With 0.1 ohm total ESR in the circuit this gives 300 amps and thus a correspondingly enormous amount of watts... in this case there is a bang, part of the die is vaporized, usually leaving a small crater in the plastic package, like a mini volcano. If the power supply is strong enough, there can even be a jet of flames...

Answer (score 3):

> I turned on the voltage and immediatly saw smoke coming out of my transistor.

It is more likely that you saw smoke coming off the surface of your transistor. This may be plastic or some low temperature component of the plastic starting to burn.

- What kills semiconductor devices is excessive temperature.
- Temperature rise depends on the thermal mass of the object, the electrical power input and the cooling rate.
- Temperature rise takes *time*.
- The temperature (in normal operation) will stabilise at that value where heat lost to ambient or cooling system equals the electrical power input.

You were fortunate to save your devices by your quick reaction.

Comment: +1.. may not just be the surface though. Blown a cavity off the front of a TO220 before and had it still appear to work. Pressure builds up really fast inside.